# How do I format MultiDimensional JSON Array body into data class in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I got this JSON response for the JSON Base (Let's say this is JSON_A):

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "vendorTitle": "erlangga",
      "vendor_id": "178",
      "userstat": true
    }
  ],
  "stas": [],
  "code": 200,
}
```

And this JSON, I have to put this inside my base JSON, but I get confused because of the format. I don't know where should I put it inside my base JSON. Let's say this is JSON_B.

```
{
  "query": [
    [
      "vendorTitle",
      "consists",
      "erlangga"
    ],
    [
      "userstat",
      "true"
    ]
  ]
}
```

So, I use this to retrieve a list when the user tries to search for vendorName
When I use Generate JSON to POJO Class in the Android studio plugin it only gives me this:

```
data class QueryResponse(
        val query: String
)
```

Is this the correct data class format for this kind of JSON? Where should I put my JSON_B to JSON_A. I'm kinda new to this kind of formatting, please kindly help me, Thank you, I really appreciate it a lot.

The response when using JSON_A :

> nombu, britishpublication, erlangga, melayu, arabic

The response when using JSON_A and QueryResponse :

> arabic, britishpublication, erlangga, melayu

My current DataClass looks like this :

```
data class JsonA(
    val code: Int,
    val result: List<String>,
    val userStat: Boolean
)
```

and JsonA result :

```
data class JsonA_Item(
        val id: Int,
        val vendorTitle: String,
        val vendor_id: String,
        val userstat: Boolean
)
```

Comment: what you can do is create 2 separate model class. call both API fetch data and at the end you can simply add one object to another pojo / model class..

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi any example of that?

Comment: tell me one thing are you calling API successfully.? and mapping its response on model class or not.?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi yes it is successfully works.
basically like this : When user search for a value in a list-> the response will be like this 

`{
    "query" : [["vendorTitle","contain","erlangga"],["userstat","true"]]
}`

but when the user doesn't search for the value the response will look like this :
`{
    "query" : [["userstat","true"]]
}`

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi my current data class look like above, I've edited my description

Comment: simply merge both objects in single object and use as per your requirement .

Answer (score 1):

Your `JSON_A` POJO should be like this:

```
data class JsonA(
    var code: Int?,
    var result: List<Result>?,
    var stas: List<Any>?
)
```

the `Result` POJO:

```
data class Result(
    var id: Int?,
    var userstat: Boolean?,
    var vendorTitle: String?,
    var vendor_id: String?
)
```

and the `QueryResponse` POJO:

```
data class QueryResponse(
    var query: List<List<String>>?
)
```

Comment: What about the JSON_B?

Comment: Okay, thank you @MojoJojo
but, I want to ask again, How do I call the QueryResponse to display this multidimensional list? , Do I need to call the JSON_A, instead of QueryResponse?.
Because both of them will return 2 different lists, like the QueryResponse is the new update of JSON_A response

Comment: you can see the difference between that two JSON above, I've edited my description, thank you @MojoJojo

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating multiple object classes simply merge your response in single object and use values according to your need.

```
  data class Response (
        val code: Int =-1,
        val result: List<String>=arrayListOf<String>(),
        val userStat: Boolean=false,
        val id: Int?=-1,
        val vendorTitle: String?="",
        val vendor_id: String?="",
        val userstat: Boolean =false
    )
```